Jetpack compose Pressing back button during navigation transition can lead to a broken UI state
@Composable
fun FileManagerNavHost(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    navController: NavHostController,
) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = HomePageRoute,
        enterTransition = {
            slideIntoContainer(
                AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Start,
                tween(500)
            )
        },
        exitTransition = {
            slideOutOfContainer(
                AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Start,
                tween(500)
            )
        },
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        homePageRoute(
            onNavigateToFileList = { directory ->
                navController.navigateSafely(FileListRoute(directory))
            }
        )
        fileListRoute(
            onNavigateToFileList = { directory ->
                navController.navigateSafely(FileListRoute(directory))
            }
        )
        imageViewerRoute()
    }
}

Above is code of my NavHost. I have provided a simple animation for enterTransition and exitTransition
I am facing a bug where if I press the back button when I'm in the middle of navigating from Screen A to Screen B, it will partially show the screen in between A and B and it just freezes there.
Is there any workaround for this issue?

